# Finding a $2$-Sylow subgroup of $S_4$

Tags: group-theory, permutations, sylow-theory

I’m trying to follow the following approach in order to find a $2$-Sylow subgroup of $S_4$: let $H$ be such subgroup. Then $|H|=8$, and we know it can’t be included in $A_4$ because $8$ doesn’t divide $A_4=12$.

Now I’ve been told I should consider the union $H=(H\cap A_n) \cup \tau(H \cap A_n)$, where $\tau \in H \setminus A_n$… which is apparently a disjoint union, but I don’t see why right now.

Also, I can see that this would imply that the order of $\tau$ is $2$, but I’m not sure why this shows that $H\cap A_n$ is a $2$-Sylow subgroup of $A_4$… I’m probably misunderstanding something.

Comment: It's a disjoint union because cosets of a subgroup $G_1$ of a group $G_2$ partition $G_2$.

Comment: @Shaun I see! And how do they know there’s only two cosets? (I mean, how do they know $\tau^2=1$?)

Comment: I'm afraid I can't help you there, at least not right now. Perhaps someone else can though.

Comment: I think you have to explain why "I can see that this would imply that the order of $\tau$ is $2$" before anyone can help you.

Comment: $D_4$ of order $8$ acts on the vertices of a square and so embeds into $ S_4$, so it is a Sylow  2-subgroup.

Comment: There are exactly two cosets by simple arithmetic. $H  \cap A_4$ is a Sylow $2$-subgroup of $A_4$ and has order $4$. BUT you cannot conclude from this that $\tau^2 = 1$ - that's just does not follow. As it happens, you can choose $\tau$ to have order either $2$ or $4$, but in general there would be no guarantee that this was possible.

Comment: Thanks everyone for the help. I will try to figure out the details I was missing.